# Allow users to select a part of a links text

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to allow user to click inside a link and select some part of the text? (In some or any modern browser.)

Is there a CSS/HTML solution for this? Or is there any other, maybe a JS, solution?

For example if you want to select *"Want to select this."* in the following example.

HTML:

```
<a href="#">
    Don't want to select this.
    Want to select this.
    Don't want to select this.
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10em;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #eee;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

<kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L8px2/)</kbd>

I've tried to use the following for Google Chrome. But it didn't allow one to select the text inside of the link, just disables the dragging of the element.

```
-webkit-user-select: all;
-webkit-user-drag: none;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a round about way to achieve this in JavaScript. You can replace the links with spans and handle the mousedown and up to see if a selection was made, and if not simulate the link click.

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/L8px2/2/

**CODE:**

```
var posX = -1, posY = -1;

$('a').each(function() {
    var a = $(this);
    a.replaceWith(
            $('<span />')
                .text(a.text())
                .attr({
                    href: a.attr('href'),
                    target: a.attr('target')
                })
                .addClass('selectable')
    );
});

$(document).on('mousedown', '.selectable', function(evt) {
    posX = evt.pageX;
    posY = evt.pageY;
});
$(document).on('mouseup', '.selectable', function(evt) {
    if(evt.pageX == posX && evt.pageY == posY) {
        alert('no selection. simulate click.');
        window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
        // TODO: handle target attribute correctly
    }
});
```

Comment: +1. Altho I'm more curious if there is a JS-less solution. Probably not.

Comment: Yeah, a clean CSS-only solution would have been the cleanest. But with `-webkit-user-select` not working the way it should, it seems very difficult.

Comment: Unfortunately, this breaks common interactions on `<a>` elements like right-click, Ctrl+click and middle-click. Not that I have a better solution to offer... :(

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `<span>` element to those lines you don't wish to select, and then apply `-webkit-user-select: none`.

For example:

```
<a href="#">
    <span class="no-select">Don't want to select this.</span>
    Want to select this.
    <span class="no-select">Don't want to select this.</span>
</a>
```

And in turn:

```
span.no-select {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
}
```

See this [**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/L8px2/1/). It works in Chrome, but I can't test other browsers at the minute.

Comment: With this I still can't click inside the link and select some part of the text. And the text the user wants to select is up to the user, and thus is arbitrary.

Comment: @Qtax How are you expecting to click on a link and not have it take you somewhere?

Comment: Then no, you can't. I don't understand how you expect the text to be up to the user, though :/ Can you elaborate more on that, since your question specifically indicated text that should not be highlighted...

Comment: A click is a click (mouse down, optional move of up to 4px (on Windows at least), and finally a mouse up on the same element). It does not involve ("major") mouse movement or text selection. Click and drag/select is not a click, it's a mouse down (in this case inside the element), and mouse up is somewhere "far" away, and possibly completely outside the element.